# Is it still possible to see where mobs can spawn by pressing F7 in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my Minecraft world, I am trying to figure out where mobs can't spawn (mainly to make my nearby village safe, as I plan to trade with them), but I my personal computer's browser isn't working, and any easy resources aren't available or aren't working (trust me, I tried to use other browsers, but for some reason I am the unluckiest person in the world right now and can't get it to work).

Anyways, when I googled "***can you still see where mobs can spawn by pressing*** <kbd>F7</kbd> ***in minecraft***", the information that I got said that it was from 2019, but couldn't access the website for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was never a feature in Vanilla. You must have used some mod. MiniHUD for example can show crosses on spawnable spaces and it's updated to 1.20.1.

Comment: Thanks. After posting this, I looked around in Minecraft `Keybinds...`, looking for any options for this, but couldn't find it. I found it on the internet years ago, but could never find out if it was a mod or an actual feature. I never thought about it until recently, so that's why I was asking.